# React / Next - importing component from external library cause : Element type is invalid: expected a string or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-dom

I'm trying to create a React components library then integrated into a NextJs project.
In the library I have a generic "CmsBlock" component that take a type and the data and generate a component (Paragraph or ZigZag). Here is the code :

src/Block.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import Paragraph from "./components/Paragraph/Paragraph";
import ZigZag from "./components/ZigZag/ZigZag";

const CMS_BLOCKS: {
  [key: string]: any;
} = {
  ZigZag: ZigZag,
  Paragraph: Paragraph,
};

const CmsBlock = ({ type, data }: { type: string; data: unknown }) => {
  const CurrentBlock = CMS_BLOCKS[type];

  if (!CurrentBlock) {
    throw new Error("Unknown block type");
  }

  return <CurrentBlock data={data} />;
};

export default CmsBlock;
```

src/components/Paragraph/Paragraph.tsx

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { CmsProps } from "../props";

export interface ParagraphData {
  text: string;
}
const Paragraph: FC<CmsProps<ParagraphData>> = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <section className="text-gray-600 dark:text-gray-300">
      <p className="leading-relaxed">{data.text}</p>
    </section>
  );
};

Paragraph.defaultProps = {
  data: {
    text: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Et ullam quis et repellat nulla sit consequatur praesentium est voluptatem dolorem ut voluptate eveniet At consequatur veniam aut vero pariatur? Et consequatur repudiandae ut illum voluptas est unde dolore et enim blanditiis et asperiores perspiciatis et rerum eveniet ad molestiae pariatur. Aut nostrum itaque a assumenda consequatur ad numquam expedita ex rerum officia? Eum delectus incidunt quo incidunt nemo est itaque similique est tempora iure.`,
  },
};

export default Paragraph;
```

And then my index.ts (input for rollup)

```
export { default as CmsBlock } from "./Block";
```

In my NextJS project, I use the CmsBlock like that :

```
import { CmsBlock } from "cms-components";

export default function Bloc(data: {
  blocks: { id: string; type: string; data: unknown }[];
}) {
  return (
    <section className="container mx-auto my-4 space-y-10">
      {data.blocks.map((block) => (
        <CmsBlock data={block.data} type={block.type} key={block.id} />
      ))}
    </section>
  );
}
```

It loads well but I have that modal with error  :

> Unhandled Runtime Error
>
> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in
> components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got:
> undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file
> it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `Bloc`.

It look like I messed up with a import/export but I can't handle to find it.

[image: result]

**edit :** Just discover that when I try a "next build", I have that error :

```
./src/pages/[[...slug]].tsx
Attempted import error: 'CmsBlock' is not exported from '@cleverconnect/cms-components' (imported as 'CmsBlock').
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that `block.data` and/or `block.type` are undefined when you pass them to `CmsBlock` in the `Bloc` component. You can check that the `data.blocks` is not empty before mapping it.

Either approach bellow would do:

```js
import { CmsBlock } from "cms-components";

export default function Bloc(data: {
  blocks: { id: string; type: string; data: unknown }[];
}) {
  return (
    <section className="container mx-auto my-4 space-y-10">
      {data.blocks && data.blocks.map((block) => (
        <CmsBlock data={block.data} type={block.type} key={block.id} />
      ))}
    </section>
  );
}
```

or :

```js
import { CmsBlock } from "cms-components";

export default function Bloc(data: {
  blocks: { id: string; type: string; data: unknown }[];
}) {
  return (
    <section className="container mx-auto my-4 space-y-10">
      {data.blocks.length ? data.blocks.map((block) => (
        <CmsBlock data={block.data} type={block.type} key={block.id} />
      )) : <> Some custom fallback message here: no data yet, sorry</>}
    </section>
  );
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It doesn't work with the checks. Even if I add a console.log, data.blocks is fine. I have add an image. It is weird because I can see the result ( "Hello Stack Overflow", a Paragraph component ) under the error...

Comment: just added an error when doing a next build

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: this is not really a solution, but more a dirty workaround.

I have exactly the same problem. It seems as thought the imported component is only `undefined` when NextJs does the initial render. Not sure exactly how that happens, but you can do a check to ensure that the import is not undefined before moving on with the real rendering.

```
import { CmsBlock } from "cms-components";

export default function Bloc(data: {
  blocks: { id: string; type: string; data: unknown }[];
}) {
  return CmsBlock ? (
    <section className="container mx-auto my-4 space-y-10">
      {data.blocks.map((block) => (
        <CmsBlock data={block.data} type={block.type} key={block.id} />
      ))}
    </section>
  ) : null;
}
```